# Unable to create-edit components with specific schema

Tags: 2013, schema, componentpresentation

We use Tridion 2013 environment and with two schema we recently have issues. In the past we were able create/edit components using these schema without issues.

Now if we open existing components or try to create new ones with the schema the input form is not displayed correctly in Content Explorer, so we are not able to edit the fields. Only the labels of the fields are displayed, but there is no edit field anymore.

Also if we do changes to the components and save and close them the changes are not saved. So if we reopen the components the changes are gone. We have this issue with different Firefox and IE versions.

One of the schema was changed 2 days ago, but rolling back to older schema did not fix the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: What did you change in the schema 2 days ago?

Answer (score 4):

The Tridion GUI can sometimes cache very aggressively. Try closing your browser entirely, then opening it up and flushing the cache completely before returning to Tridion. Then perhaps you will see the schema changes correctly reflected in the component pop-up instead of the problems you now have.

If that doesn't work, you should check for hotfixes that apply to your browser - in particular the recent patch to deal with an unfortunate breaking change in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Else try to use some different browser because as i remember that during development in my project I faced one weird behavior of  browser, while creating the multimedia component in chrome browser I need to select image for component but after selecting image it was not comes in component and then I used different browser and every thing working fine.

So my concern here is that whenever you face these kind of issue try to delete your cache or restart your CME application.

Answer (score 0):

We today restarted our Tridion Environment that did not help. Also I topened the Content Manager with a pc I never used to access an Tridion environment, but this also did not help, so it should not be a caching problem.
We have the problem with IE and Firefox. In Chrome it works, but out customer will not work with Chrome.

Any other suggestions will be welcome ....